# Facebook Login in React native, compile error

Tags: react-native, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement Facebook Login in react native.

I followed every step in this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started

But I'm getting strange compile error:
[image]

When I could compile earlier, I got error about RCTFBLoginButton not found.
[image]

Can anyone help me please?
Is there a tutorial or example I can follow?

here are the dependencies I used:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

Thanks,
Kenji

Comment: Please mention your react-native version and react-native-fbsdk version too.

Comment: react-native: 0.63.4, react-native-fbsdk: "^3.0.0"

Comment: I have put an answer if this not works then please share a reproducible code with me and I will fix it.

Comment: hi @WaheedAkhtar, any idea?

Comment: Sorry yesterday I was a little busy, Today I will compile it and let you know.

Comment: @kchkg Which version of FBSDK you are using ?  and if its v7 have you created File.swift file on the project ?

Comment: @kchkg have you run my provided code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that you have run `pod install` after installing any native-module, This usually happens when your native-module(react-native-fbsdk) is not linked with your project, After react-native `0.60.0` auto-linking is done by react-native so it looks like either your auto-linking is broken or somehow react-native-fbsdk is not linked with your project.

Follow these steps to fix this issue.

1. pod install
2. react-native link react-native-fbsdk
3. Clean Project
4. run

Note: if still not works then try to link manually.

Edit: As you shared the reproducible code with me I manage to fix your issue, [here is a link to running code with the fixture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1raTQfb4USf783l8RCqNEiX1ATpo79l9m/view?usp=sharing)

Steps I followed to fix your issue.

1. update pod repo.
2. remove the framework files of fbsdk from the framework search path.
3. remove framework file links from linked libraries.
4. remove pods and podfile.lock and node modules.
5. re-install node modules and pods.

**Note:** **In the above-shared code I already did the above-mentioned steps so you just need to follow step number 5 to run my above shared code.**

Comment: even though I think I tried similar steps, I will try it later tonight

Comment: how to do step 3?

Comment: after I did step 1&2, when I open the xcode project, xcode crash, LOL

Comment: go to Xcode > click on the product on the top menu > clean.

Comment: so, maybe I should upload the whole project and share to you, and you can take a closer look? I created an empty project using "npx react-native init" and followed all the steps

Comment: Yes, I can see if you share your code or some other project with the issue you have.

Comment: thanks so much, here is the whole project, I just zipped it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vmocjV8EW8mqa8EUiQr3NyZnhkBbg9mn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your problem is fixed now and code is working on my machine

Comment: great! How? what was the problem?

Comment: You were using framework files which where not compatible. I removed all of them and migrated on pods.

Comment: But I couldn't even open the xcode project, xcode crashed. Could you show me what you've changed? and share the project to me, so I can compare the differences?

Comment: Are you trying to run my provided code and then it crashes?

Comment: the one I gave you is the one crashed in my xcode

Comment: I have shared my code in which i did all the fixes you can use that one.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1raTQfb4USf783l8RCqNEiX1ATpo79l9m/view
This link is also attached to the above answer.

Comment: actually, I still can't build your fixed project. I change my mac from MacBook Pro to a Mac mini m1, now I can't even pod install

Comment: I don't know what's wrong on your side but the above provided link is works fine for me

Comment: I'm having this problem at the moment:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31156?fbclid=IwAR2BUWxPORAHZWZpEN3H077VzNNzR7dTgoj1mYzck5FLAStMbOPpyoGc3RI

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue because I was importing FBSDK at wrong place in AppDelegate.m

Point is you must import before `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED`
Here is the correct way:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h" <-- IMPORT HERE! -->

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
<--- DO NOT IMPORT BELOW --->
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
```